# query two specific dates in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]I have a table as below. I want to query specific dates from the table. The dates are random and therefore i do not want to use the BETWEEN keyword. Also, the number of dates that i want to query could vary from one to many(for simplicity lets say 2 distinct dates.

```
create table temptable(id serial primary key not null,myTimestamp timestamp);
insert into temptable(myTimestamp) values ('2020-09-25 02:02:51.99');
insert into temptable(myTimestamp) values ('2020-08-24 12:20:51.111');
insert into temptable(myTimestamp) values ('2020-09-23 13:20:51.286');
```

The following query is executed hoping to get two distinct dates.

```
select * 
from temptable 
where myTimestamp::date = date '2020-09-23' 
and myTimestamp::date = date '2020-08-24';
```

The above query executes on pgadmin but nothing is listed on the table. If i use OR operator, i can see one date returned but that i not what i want. I want both the dates

Please advice

Thanks

Comment: Think about your query: you are requesting all rows where the column contains two different values at the same time - this will never be true. You want `OR`, not `AND`. When you use `OR` you only see one row, because there is no row for `2020-08-24` (only for `2020-09-24`)

Comment: Hi @codeheadache In your data from your question there is only '2020-09-23' there is no '2020-08-24'. So when you add or you see only one row...

Comment: I have updated the insert statements. I want to list out the two dates that i have queried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `in`:

```
select * 
from temptable 
where myTimestamp::date in (date '2020-09-23', date '2020-08-24');
```

However, this might be more efficient with inequalities for the date comparisons:

```
select * 
from temptable 
where (myTimestamp >= '2020-09-23'::timestamp and
       myTimestamp < '2020-09-24'::timestamp
      ) or
      (myTimestamp >= '2020-08-24'::timestamp and
       myTimestamp < '2020-08-25'::timestamp
      )
```

This is more index friendly.

Or if you prefer:

```
select * 
from temptable tt join
     (values ('2020-09-23'::timestamp), ('2020-08-24'::timestamp)
     ) v(ts)
     on myTimestamp >= v.ts and
        myTimestamp < v.ts + interval '1 day';
```

Comment: The query with the in KEYWORD helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So, as it has been already commented, all you need is to replace `and` with `or`

```
select * 
from temptable 
where myTimestamp::date = date '2020-09-23' 
or myTimestamp::date = date '2020-08-24';
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3014d9aa98c9f6b47563c0d2b8bb8af4)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried exactly the same as your query. But i am getting different output on pgadmin. There is nothing listed. Is this a bug?

Comment: What do you @codeheadache get with this: `select myTimestamp::date from temptable` Do you get same results as me : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dcc2ae335a5410e4541e0982fce59d87

Comment: Yes. For the query ```select myTimestamp::date from temptable``` i get the same output as yours.However, for the query in my question, the output is blank, as shown in the picture. 
For the time being however, i think Gordon solution helped. Thank you for your response

Comment: OK, @codeheadache, but you told in your question when you add `OR` operator you can see only one date. Then you have corrected the data in your table... Then you said that with `OR` operator you can not see anything ? Is that true ?